# Getting Spyder IDE to work with QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, installation, osgeo4w, spyder, conda

I was hoping someone could help me get Spyder working with QGIS. I am finding the python editor limiting within QGIS as I would like to debug my code, use the variable explorer, and be able to run highlighted code. I have tried two routes:

---

**Route 1: Install Spyder within the OSGeo4W QGIS python instance**

I installed OSGeo4W Network Installer (64 bit) v3.2 and opened OSGeo4W Shell and typed:

```
py3-env
python -m pip install spyder
spyder3
```

But I am getting errors in my IPython console:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site.py", line 177
file=sys.stderr)
```

Also, when I put in

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
```

into my python script, it complains with `unable to detect undefined names`

I noticed all the QGIS files are in `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\`

---

**Route 2: Create new conda environment and install QGIS via conda**

I used the install instructions at this url: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis

I create a new conda environment and then typed:

```
conda install -c conda-forge qgis 
conda install spyder
start spyder
```

My IPython console is fine (i.e. no errors as route 1), but I get errors when trying to import qgis.core etc into my script as in route 1.

I noticed that conda installed all the QGIS files to `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\<my_env>\Library\`

---

Would anyone have any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Concerning route 1: I didn't use spyder with OSGeo4W, but since Spyder uses Qt5 you also should run qt5_env.bat bevore starting it. And: qgis 3.4 is LTR, it comes with python 3.7.0.